# ScrollView contentOffset always count to zero

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, ios-simulator

I'm dealing with `UIScrollView` in my app. I have set the delegate , but when I scroll the scroll view in vertical down direction its `contentOffset.y` is always zero. I am working on ios7 simulator. I can't understand why this issue is there? Does anyone have any solution?

```
if (!scrollView) { 
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70)]; 
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView]; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: if (!scrollView) {
        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70)];
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
         self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    }

Comment: [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, yAxis+100)];

Comment: Edit your question, don't put it in comment

Comment: There is nothing in here where you are responding to scrolling in the scroll view.

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered with exactly the same problem, it turned out that I used the NSLog wrong.

The original line:

```
NSLog("%d", scrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

Which should be:

```
NSLog("%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

It's really trivia, but hope this could help people like me who searched here.